# Merge two lists with alternative elements in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm new Haskell and try to practice my Haskell skill.

I want to implement a function to merge two lists so that the items are alternative from each list.

```
["a", "b", "c"]
["1", "2", "3"]
```

After the merger.

```
["a", "1", "b", "2", "c", "3"]
```

Here is my Haskell code

```
mergeList::[String]->[String]->[String]
mergeList [] [] = []
mergeList  _ [] = []
mergeList [] _  = []
mergeList (x:xs) (y:ys) = x:y:mergeList xs ys
```

The code works as long as the lengths of two lists are the same.

But I want to have some error checking on the lengths of the two lists.

If the length of two lists are different, then I want to report an error.

```
mergeList::[String]->[String]->[String]
mergeList l r | length l /= length r = error "report an error"
              | otherwise =
```

How can I finish the otherwise section?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to define a behaviour for non-same size lists and let higher up code check sizes if they need to?

Answer (score 8):

Using `error` is discouraged.  In Haskell we like to define our functions for all possible inputs, so that the type system can guide us to write correct programs.  If your function is invalid for lists of different lengths, one way would be to use `Maybe`.

```
mergeList :: [a] -> [a] -> Maybe [a]
mergeList [] [] = Just []
mergeList (x:xs) (y:ys) =
    case mergeList xs ys of
        Just merged -> Just (x:y:merged)
        Nothing     -> Nothing
mergeList _ _ = Nothing
```

There are more succinct ways to write this, but I'm staying near the ground floor.

Now users of `mergeList` are required to define what to do in the case that they passed lists of two different lengths.

Comment: On the other hand, using `Maybe` in this sort of situation loses laziness. An alternative is to (effectively) compose `Maybe` with the base functor of `[]` before taking the fixed point: `data MList a = Nil | Cons a (MList a) | Error`. This lets the *caller* choose the error handling mechanism.

Comment: Yeah, it's nice, though it's no longer a standard list.  Another way is to use `Writer Error [a]` for some error monoid, so you get laziness up until the point when you need to know whether there was an error.  But OP is clearly a beginner so I wanted to show them what I consider the most obvious Haskellish solution to their problem, even if it does have some subtle drawbacks.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would probably just to do a check beforehand, then route the main work to an auxiliary function:

```
mergeList::[String]->[String]->[String]
mergeList xs ys
    | length xs /= length ys = error "Lists must be the same length" 
    | otherwise go xs ys
    where
        go [] [] = []
        go  _ [] = []
        go [] _  = []
        go (x:xs) (y:ys) = x:y:go xs ys
```

The check is done in the main function, and if the list's are the same size, they're handed to an internal function that does the main processing. Note how `go` is just your original function; it's just been internalized within a wrapper function. You could use a more descriptive name than `go`; I was trying to keep it brief.

It's been awhile since I've written Haskell, so I apologize for any syntax issues.

You could also generalize the function by changing the signature to:

```
mergeList::[a]->[a]->[a]
```

Since you're not doing anything specific to Strings in the function.

Answer (score 2):

In your pattern matching raise an error if EXACTLY one of the lists is empty.
So you would have

```
mergeList (x: xs) (y: ys) = x: y: mergeList xs ys
mergeList []      []      = []
mergeList _       _       = error "your error"  -- falling through to this pattern means that exactly one of the lists is empty
```

It is somewhat redundant to check whether lengths of 2 lists are equal, since 'length' has O(n) complexity, meaning that you would go over lists twice (in a case of equal lengths).

As luqui correctly pointed out, there are more elegant ways to solve the problem using Maybe type. When you learn about functors (and Maybe is an instance of class Functor), you could write:

```
mergeList :: [a] -> [a] -> Maybe [a]
mergeList (x: xs) (y: ys) = fmap (\rest -> x: y: rest) $ mergeList xs ys
mergeList []      []      = Just []
mergeList _       _       = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

Your otherwise function it might be something like this:

```
otherwise = reverse $ foldl (\a (x,y) -> x:y:a) [] (x `zip` y)
```

Example:

```
Prelude> let y = ["a", "b", "c"]
Prelude> let x = ["1", "2", "3"]
Prelude> reverse $ foldl (\a (x,y) -> x:y:a) [] (x `zip` y)
["a","1","b","2","c","3"]
```

or the elliptic00 solution with foldr that avoids the usage of the `reverse`:

```
 otherwise = foldr ((x, y) a -> x:y:a) [] (x `zip` y)
```

Comment: beautiful solution:)   i chagne it a little bit:  foldr (\(x, y) a -> x:y:a) [] (x `zip` y) without  reverse

Comment: yes I thought to use `foldr` soon, but I usually start with `foldl` then refactor :)

Comment: @elliptic00 You can escape backticks in comments as follows: `\\``. This allows you to write `foldr (\(x, y) a -> x : y : a) [] (x \`zip\` y)`.

Answer (score 0):

luqui points out that we like to be safe in Haskell, avoiding `error`. But waiting till we get to the end of at least one list before yielding anything throws away any hope of laziness. One option is to toss error handling to the caller. We can fake up lists like this:

```
import Data.Bifunctor
import Data.Bifunctor.Fix
import Data.Bifunctor.Tannen

data ListF l a = NilF | ConsF a l

instance Bifunctor ListF where
  bimap _ _ NilF = NilF
  bimap f g (ConsF a l) = ConsF (f a) (g l)

{-instance Bifoldable ListF where ...

instance Bitraversable ListF where ... -}

type List = Fix ListF
```

But we can add in error handling:

```
type EList e = Fix (Tannen (Either e) ListF)
```

An `EList e a` is either an error of type `e`, a `NilF` or a `ConsF` holding an `a` and another `EList e a`.

This composition approach, however, ends up being very verbose, confusing, and somewhat inefficient. A better approach in practice is to use a totally custom list type:

```
data EList' e a = Error e | Nil | Cons a (EList' e a)
```